# Why does the robot in Karel not stop even if he stands on a beeper?

Tags: karel

I am trying to solve the problem (2.4.1, SolveTheMaze) but for some reason, the robot doesn't stop when he's on a beeper - he just keeps going. It seems like I have created an infinite loop. **Here's a picture of the problem:**

*[Karel: SolveTheMaze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIM5s.png)*

**Here is the code:**

```
void solveTheMaze()
{
  while (!onBeeper())
  {
     CrossABarrier();   
  }  
}

void CrossABarrier()
{
   while (frontIsClear())
   {
       moveForward();
       if (frontIsClear() && leftIsClear())
       {
           turnLeft();
       }
       rightOrleftNotClear();
       while (!frontIsClear())
       {
           turnLeft();
       }       
   }  
}


 void rightOrleftNotClear()
{
   if (!frontIsClear() && !leftIsClear())
   {
      turnRight();
   }
   else if (!frontIsClear() && !rightIsClear())
   {
      turnLeft();
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here my solution.
Not realy smart but it works :)

```
void mazeFind()
{
    while (!onBeeper())
    {
        if (leftIsClear())
        {
            turnLeft();
            moveForward();
        }
        else if (frontIsClear())
        {
            moveForward();
        }
        else if (rightIsClear())
        {
            turnRight();
            moveForward();
        }
        else
        {
            turnAround();
            moveForward();
        }
    }
}
```